# Unable to set spinner adapter on onItemSelected of first spinner

Tags: android, retrofit, android-spinner

i have two spinners, say categories and subcategories. OnItemSelected of categories spinner i need to set the adapter for sub_categories spinner.I am able to set spinner for categories. But sub_categories spinner is creating trouble.

These arraylist are coming from servers, i made it static.
Looking into my code will give you proper idea that where i am mistaken.

This is my categories List:

```
public static ArrayList<String> categories=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayAdapter<String> mArryAdtSpnnr;
```

and in the response.success, i am trying to do the following:

```
 for(int i=0;i<mArray.length;i++){categories.add(mArray[i].getName());}
```

Here in this activity, where i need 2 spinners:

```
  private void initializeWidgets() {
        mspinner_categories=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_categories);
        mspinner_categories.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mspinner_subcategories=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_subcategories);

        ProfessionalListActivity.mArryAdtSpnnr = new ArrayAdapter<String>( EditProfileActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ProfessionalListActivity.categories);

        mspinner_categories.setAdapter(ProfessionalListActivity.mArryAdtSpnnr);    
    }
```

and on its item selected:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this,"Selected Item is: "+item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // mspinner_subcategories.setSelection(position);
        SubListProActivity.mArrySpnnr=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (EditProfileActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            SubListProActivity.subcategories);
        mspinner_subcategories.setAdapter(SubListProActivity.mArrySpnnr);
    }
```

I am setting second spinner adapter on click of first spinner. But nothing is displayed on this spinner. I did similar code to the other activity. 
I am confused, this may be because in ProfessionalListActivity i am getting a category_id also, so that corresponding sublist gets opened. But in spinners i am adding it directly.
Edit:
Sublist class:

```
public static ArrayList<String> subcategories=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> mArrySpnnr;
```

in its response.success

```
for(int i=0;i<mArray.length;i++){
    subcategories.add(mArray[i].getName());
}
```

Please help

Comment: Where adding data in `SubListProActivity.subcategories` ?

Comment: You never added the `subCategory` list to list. how can you suppose to the result.

Comment: WHAT trouble? i have a working solution for this, but i need to understand WHAT is happening a bit more precisely.  please supply screen shots, if possible (andropid studio and eclipse allow you to take screen capture images)   :)

Comment: @tonygil onitemselected of first spinner, i want my second spinner comes into existence with corresponding list in it. But the 2nd spinner is showing blank

Comment: @tonygil can you please help

Comment: yes, i can help, but i am out of the office now.  will be back in 4 hours.  i recommend you to to not CREATE second spinner ONCLICK first spinner.  simply DISPLAY it.  if you cant work it out on your own (i couldnt and needed a bit of help), i'll post my working code.

Comment: @tonygil that means alot.

Answer (score 0):

This code approaches your problem as an `ExpandableList` and is from a working app.  First is the listener for a button that calls the activity which:

1. displays a list of clickable first level options, which, when activated,
2. display drop down lists of clickable second-level options, when activated
3. display groups of 3 option radio buttons (only 1 selected button per radio group)

The original application is an (agri) inspection system - the user selects from groups of problems (1st level: insects, funghi, weeds), which problems are occuring (2nd level: insects[army worms, ladybugs, ants], funghi[stem rot, rust, mildew], weeds[common grass, african grass, morning glory]).

For each selected 2nd level option a radio button group to select the severity of problem pops up and the user must choose levels 1 (default), 2 OR 3.

Data is stored to be consumed elsewhere.

Calling the activity which displays a layout dedicated to INSPECTION, sending along the data that will populate the expandable lists.

```
private final OnClickListener btnDoneOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      String input = areaName.getText().toString();
      // english version
      //String[] groupName = {"INSECTS", "WEEDS", "FUNGHI", "CLIMATE", "VARIOUS"};
      String[] groupName = {"INSETOS", "ERVAS INVASORAS", "FUNGOS", "CLIMA", "VARIOS"};
      String[][] childName = {  { "Cigarrinha","Falsa medideira","Lagarta cartucho","Lagarta rosca","Percevejo (geral)"},
                { "Argentino","Buva","Capim colchao","Carrapicho","Corda viola","Falso Argentino","Leiteiro","Picao","Tiguera Milho","Tiguera Soja"},
                { "Antracnose","Cercospora","DFC","Ferrugem"},
                { "Erosao","Geada","Granizo","Incendio","Inundacao","Raio","Seca","Vento" },
                { "Furto","Fuga","Picada cobra" }
            };

      Intent intent00 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.xxx.yyy.zzz.AgrInspectActivity.class);
      intent00.putExtra("groupName", groupName);
      int maxLength = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<groupName.length;i++) {
          intent00.putExtra(groupName[i], childName[i]);
          maxLength = Math.max(childName[i].length, maxLength);
      }
      intent00.putExtra("arrayLength", maxLength);

      // count childrenRows and put values in ARRAY
      // to be used by CustomList to inflate layouts
      // with proper number of lines
      int[] countChild = new int[groupName.length];
      for (int j=0;j<groupName.length;j++) {
          countChild[j] = childName[j].length;
      }
      intent00.putExtra("countChild", countChild);
      startActivity(intent00);

    }
};
```

The activity proper:

```
public class AgrInspectActivity extends Activity {
    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    int arrayLength;
    String[] groups;
    String[][] children;
    int[][] array_output_data;
    String[][] array_output_data_quantity;
    int[] countChild;

    public int[][] getArray_output_data() {
        return array_output_data;
    }
    public String[][] getArray_output_data_quantity() {
        return array_output_data_quantity;
    }
    int choice = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inspection);
        ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            groups = extras.getStringArray("groupName");
            arrayLength = extras.getInt("arrayLength");
            countChild = extras.getIntArray("countChild");
            String[] tempArray = new String[arrayLength];
            children = new String[groups.length][arrayLength];
            for (int i=0;i<groups.length;i++) {
                children[i] = extras.getStringArray(groups[i]);

                // TODO delete this block debug ONLY
                Log.i("data", groups[i]+groups.length+" get array loop "+i+" / "+ tempArray.length+"/  countChild: "+countChild[i]);
                for (int j=0;j<children[i].length;j++) {
                    Log.d("data", j+" counter:temparray "+children[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        mAdapter = new InspectionMenu(this);
        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public class InspectionMenu extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context myContext;

        public InspectionMenu(Context context) {
            myContext = context;
            Log.i("data", "InspectionActivity InspectionMenu children length "+groups.length);
            array_output_data = new int[groups.length][arrayLength];
            array_output_data_quantity = new String[groups.length][arrayLength];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inspection_row, null);

            TextView childtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            childtext.setText(children[groupPosition][childPosition]);

            final RadioGroup rdg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            final RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            final RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            final RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio3);
            final EditText inspectQuantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inspection_quant);

            if (array_output_data[groupPosition][childPosition] >0) {
                //switch (Integer.parseInt(array_output_data[groupPosition][childPosition])) {
                switch (array_output_data[groupPosition][childPosition]) {
                case 1:
                    r1.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    r2.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    r3.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                }
            }

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            if (array_output_data[groupPosition][childPosition] > 0) {
                cb.setChecked(true);
                rdg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inspectQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            rdg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    if (checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
                        choice = 1;
                    } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2) {
                        choice = 2;
                    } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio3) {
                        choice = 3;
                    } else {
                        Log.e("TGTG", "radio button selection invalid in InspectionActivityOld");
                    }
                    array_output_data[groupPosition][childPosition] = (choice);
                }
            });
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked == true) { // display LEVEL (1,2,3) RADIO BUTTONS for this line
                        rdg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // redundant?
                        try {
                            inspectQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                        } catch (Exception except) {
                            Log.e("TGTG", "no open inspectQUantity  "+except.getMessage()+"  group "+groupPosition+"  child "+childPosition);
                        }
                        r1.setChecked(true);
                    } else { // hide LEVEL RADIO BUTTONS  for this line
                        rdg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        inspectQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        rdg.clearCheck();
                        array_output_data[groupPosition][childPosition] = 0;
                        array_output_data_quantity[groupPosition][childPosition] = "";
                    }

                }
            });

            if (array_output_data_quantity[groupPosition][childPosition] != null) {
                inspectQuantity.setText(array_output_data_quantity[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            }

            try  {
                inspectQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        array_output_data_quantity[groupPosition][childPosition] = arg0.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {}

                });
            } catch (Exception except) {
                Log.e("TGTG", "did not add listener QUANTITY in inspection");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return countChild[groupPosition];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
            TextView grouptext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            grouptext.setText(groups[groupPosition]);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

These are the layout files:
group.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:text="TextView" android:textSize="40px" android:paddingLeft="100px" android:paddingTop="10px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

inspection_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ln">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="weeds" 
                android:textSize="20dip" 
                android:paddingLeft="20px"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="-30px"
        >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="72px"  android:layout_marginBottom="-10px">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false" android:visibility="visible" android:text="1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="false" android:visibility="visible" android:text="2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="false" android:visibility="visible" android:text="3"/>
    </RadioGroup>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inspection_quant"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10px"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should get your ball rolling in the correct direction.

Comment: thankyou for your time. But my problem is i am unable to set adapter on click of first spinner. my list is empty when i debug. now i set notify() onclick of second spinner but it also doesnot help